# How to remove Kali Linux base from Ubuntu

Tags: 15.10, software-center, update-manager, kali, katoolin

I have mistakenly installed **Katoolin** in my Ubuntu 15.10. It has done a lot of problem in my pc & then I removed it but it wasn't totally removed. Everywhere in the system has it's effect. The main problem is my **Software Center** & **Update Manager** is not responding. What do I do now??

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do a clean install. First, back up all of your files. Next, insert an Ubuntu DVD/USB into your computer and boot to it. Finally, go through the installation process and you should be good.